# My while loop in C replays one more time than it should before it ends

Tags: c, while-loop, char, scanf, conversion-specifier

When given input, my while loops print one time extra before closing its loop.  For example, 8 7 38 3 -5 -1 q is my input that prints out

Provide 6 integer coefficients for the brute force equation solver:
Solution found: x = 3, y = 2

Run program again? Type 'q' to quit or any other key to continue:

Provide 6 integer coefficients for the brute force equation solver:
Solution found: x = 3, y = 2

Run program again? Type 'q' to quit or any other key to continue:

When it should end after the first iteration. Can anyone help me out on this? My code is pasted below

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void) 
{
   //Equations should be a1x + b1y = c2 and a2x + b2y = c2
   int a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2, x, y;
   char input;
   bool solFound = false;
   bool runAgain = true;
   
   //brute force x and y [-10, 10]
   while (runAgain == true) 
   {
      printf("Provide 6 integer coefficients for the brute force equation solver: ");
      scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d", &a1, &b1, &c1, &a2, &b2, &c2);
      for (x = -10; x<=10; x++)
      {
         for (y = -10; y<=10; y++)
         {
            if (a1*x + b1*y == c1 && a2*x + b2*y == c2)
            {
                  printf("\nSolution found: x = %d, y = %d\n\n", x, y);
                  solFound = true;
                  runAgain = false;
            }
         }
      }
      if (solFound != true)
      {
         printf("No solution found\n\n");
         runAgain = false;
      }
      scanf("%c", &input);
      printf("Run program again? Type 'q' to quit or any other key to continue:");
      if (input != 'q')
      {
         runAgain = true;
      }
      printf("\n\n");
   }
} ```
````

Comment: start with `scanf(" %c", &input);`

Comment: Which language, C or C++? Pick one and tag appropriately.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: That wouldn't help.

Comment: you're right. in that case the logic is wrong: `if (input == 'q')
      {
         runAgain = false;
      }`

Comment: or just `if (input == 'q')
      {
        break;
      }`

Comment: don't compare booleans to true or false. Just do `if (runagain)` or `if (not stopped)`. Avoid `== true` and ` != false` or such...

Answer (score 2):

For starters the variable `sqlFound` should be declared within the while loop or at least reinitialized within the while loop. For example

```
   while (runAgain == true) 
   {
       bool solFound = false;
       //...
```

Otherwise it will keep the value of a previous iteration of the loop.

In this if statement

```
  if (solFound != true)
  {
     printf("No solution found\n\n");
     runAgain = false;
  }
```

setting the variable `runAgain`

```
 runAgain = false;
```

does not make a sense because after this if statement you are asking again whether to repeat the loop

```
  printf("Run program again? Type 'q' to quit or any other key to continue:");
  if (input != 'q')
  {
     runAgain = true;
  }
```

So remove this setting

```
 runAgain = false;
```

from the if statement.

Another problem is that this call of scanf

```
  scanf("%c", &input);
```

must follow the question

```
  printf("Run program again? Type 'q' to quit or any other key to continue:");
```

And moreover the format string must contain a leading blank

```
  scanf(" %c", &input);
        ^^^^^
```

Otherwise white space characters will be read from the input stream. That is you need to write

```
  printf("Run program again? Type 'q' to quit or any other key to continue:");

  scanf(" %c", &input);

  runAgain = input != 'q' && input != 'Q';
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to a lot of trouble to make sure that `runAgain` is `false` before you ask the user to run again.  This isn't doing what you think:

```
if (solFound != true)
{
   printf("No solution found\n\n");
   runAgain = false;
}
```

Once `solFound` becomes `true`, it stays that way, and if when the program loops there is no solution, you fail to print "No solution found" as well as failing to change `runAgain` to false.

This causes a problem if `runAgain` is already `true`:

```
  if (input != 'q')
  {
     runAgain = true;
  }
```

This lets you change `false` (if there is no solution) back to `true` (by entering something other than `'q'`).  But entering `'q'` can't change `true` to `false`!

The problem only stops if `runAgain` went false and you enter `'q'`.

If you wanted to stop only based on entry of `q`, you can eliminate the connection in the first block between `solFound` and `runAgain`, and replace the second block by:

```
runAgain = (input != 'q');
```

This way `runAgain` is always changed to match the user choice, never left alone.